# How is this Map of String to String possible as a Map of String to a list of String in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Saw some working code in a project that is like the one below (of course that's just an example) but I'm extremely confused at how this is possible as a `Map<String, String>` and not `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Looked it up in the Groovy doc but I didn't see anything that explains this concept. Could someone explain if this is indeed a legit concept in Groovy?

```
static final Map<String, String> NAMES = [
   "Male": ["Bill", "Bryant", "Jack"],
   "Female": ["Lily", "Haley", "Mary"]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because of [Java's Generic Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). If you look at the internal type signatures, you will see that `NAMES` field is just a type of `java.util.Map`. Take a look at the `descriptor` of that field.

```
$ javap -s -p SomeClass
Compiled from "SomeClass.groovy"
public class SomeClass implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
  private static final java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> NAMES;
    descriptor: Ljava/util/Map;
  private static org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo $staticClassInfo;
    descriptor: Lorg/codehaus/groovy/reflection/ClassInfo;
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;
    descriptor: Z
  private transient groovy.lang.MetaClass metaClass;
    descriptor: Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;
  private static java.lang.ref.SoftReference $callSiteArray;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/ref/SoftReference;
  public SomeClass();
    descriptor: ()V

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V

  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();
    descriptor: ()Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;

  public groovy.lang.MetaClass getMetaClass();
    descriptor: ()Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;

  public void setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass);
    descriptor: (Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;)V

  static {};
    descriptor: ()V

  public static java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> getNAMES();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Map;

  private static void $createCallSiteArray_1(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V

  private static org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray $createCallSiteArray();
    descriptor: ()Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSiteArray;

  private static org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite[] $getCallSiteArray();
    descriptor: ()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
}
```

Now, that' not all. If you decompile the Groovy bytecode to the Java readable code, you will find something like this.

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import groovy.transform.Generated;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class SomeClass implements GroovyObject {
    private static final Map<String, String> NAMES;

    @Generated
    public SomeClass() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super();
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].callStatic(SomeClass.class, var1[1].call(NAMES));
    }

    static {
        Map var0 = ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"Male", ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[]{"Bill", "Bryant", "Jack"}), "Female", ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[]{"Lily", "Haley", "Mary"})});
        NAMES = var0;
    }

    @Generated
    public static Map<String, String> getNAMES() {
        return NAMES;
    }
}
```

At this level, `NAMES` field signature matches `Map<String, String>`. But look at the static constructor and how this field gets initialized. The `NAMES` field of type `Map<String, String>` gets initialized with a raw `Map` type. Also, the `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap` method returns a raw map, but it could return a parameterized map as well - you will see the same effect. If that map wasn't a raw map, the compiler would complain and throw an error because of incompatible types. But a raw map essentially allows you to assign a map that stores values that are incompatible with the parameters.

You can get the same effect in pure Java. Take a look at the following example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

final class SomeJavaClass {

    private static final Map<String, String> NAMES;

    static {
        final Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("Male", Arrays.asList("Bill", "Brian", "Jack"));

        NAMES = map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(NAMES);
        System.out.println(((Object) NAMES.get("Male")).getClass());
    }
 }
```

When we execute its `main` method, we will get the following output:

```
{Male=[Bill, Brian, Jack]}
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

In this example, we had to cast `NAMES.get("Male")` to `Object`, because otherwise, we would get a `ClassCastException` - an `ArrayList` cannot be cast to `String`. But when you cast to `Object` explicitly, you can get an `ArrayList` from a map that, by definition, should keep only string values.

This is known Java behavior - generic types get erased so the raw types can be compatible with pre Java 1.5 versions. Groovy for its dynamic capabilities operates often on raw classes like `Map`, or `List`, and thus it can silently overcome some of those limitations.

If you want to use more restricted type checks, you can use `@groovy.transform.TypeChecked` annotation to keep Groovy's dynamic behavior and add more restrictive type checks. With this annotation added, your class won't compile anymore.